# How to force call of componentWillMount method using stacks?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using reactnavigation with DrawerNavigator to create navigation stack.

I navigate from the client list screen to the client registration screen.
When registering a customer I want to return to the list screen with the list of all registered clients. But the componentWillMount is not called when I return to the client list screen.

Does anyone know how to force the method call componentWillMount When am I browsing through screens?

I searched the internet and saw that I can use redux or mobx to manage the states.But my project is so small that I do not see the need to use something like that. Is there any way to do this in a simple way?

I read something about Context API, does anyone know if I can solve the problem with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your ListScreen, you can do this:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.navigationListener = this.props.navigation.addListener(
      'willFocus',
      this.stuffsYouWantToDo
    )
  }
```

So every time you navigate back to ListScreen, it will call `stuffsYouWantToDo` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **two** methods for that.

**1) using callback**

In your **Listing screen**, when you open register screen passes callback props.

```
class ListingScreen extends Component {

    // this method will call when you back from register screen to listing screen
    getRegisterUserList(listOfRegisterUser) {
        this.setState({ listOfRegisterUser: listOfRegisterUser }) //do whatever fuctionality you want to perform with listOfRegisterUser
    }

    render() {
        const navigation = this.props.navigation;
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={navigation.navigate('RegisterScreen', { callback: this.getRegisterUserList.bind(this) })}> // pass callback when you call your register screen
                <Text>Navigate to register screen</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
}
```

And In your **register screen**, after successfully register call that callback and pass your list in it.

```
if (this.props.navigation.state &&
            this.props.navigation.state.params &&
            this.props.navigation.state.params.callback) {
            this.props.navigation.state.params.callback(registerUserList); //you can pass your list here
        }
        this.props.navigation.goBack(null); //this is for back from register screen to listing screen
```

**2) using DeviceEventEmiter**

Add Listener to your listing screen

```
import { DeviceEventEmitter } from 'react-native';

    class ListingScreen extends Component {

    componentWillMount(){
     this.registerUserListener= 
         DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('RegisterUser', (e) => {
            //when you successfully register. this listener is called
           // perform your logic for getting register user list
        });
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.registerUserListener.remove();
    }

    }
```

And in your register screen, call that listener when the user is successfully registered.

```
import { DeviceEventEmitter } from 'react-native';

class RegisterScreen extends Component {

//emit listener when user is successfully register
   successfullyRegisterUser(){
      DeviceEventEmitter.emit('RegisterUser', { isRegister: true });
   }

}
```